# REST API/Community endpoint - allowChatter​AccessWithoutLogin

Tags: community, rest-api

I tried to use [Community endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_community.htm),
I'm interested in using the key  allowChatter​AccessWithoutLogin = Specifies if guest users can access public groups without logging in

This key changes when I change the value of the following setting: 
Community setup -> Administration -> Preferences -> Give guest users access to public Chatter API requests

This isn't as the description of this key says.
Anyone can give an explanation about it?

Thanks